# How to detect which event is being handled from multiple events?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events, event-handling

## My problem:

I need to detect what event (e.g. TextChanged) is currently being handled from within the handling Sub that's handling multiple objects/events. I cannot find examples online (though this may be a terminological issue). I already know how to detect the object but I do not know how to detect the event.

## To reproduce:

1. In Visual Studio, in design mode, drag two text boxes onto a fresh form.
2. Use the following as is:

**Code:**

```
Private Sub TextBox_CombinedEvents(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Enter,
               TextBox2.Enter, TextBox1.TextChanged, TextBox2.TextChanged,
               TextBox1.Leave, TextBox2.Leave
    Dim detectedEvent as String = "?"
    If detectedEvent = "Enter" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Text has been entered.")
    Elseif detectedEvent = "TextChanged" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Text has been changed.")
    Elseif detectedEvent = "Leave" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Text box has been left.")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Event not detected.")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You should separate the event types.

Comment: See: [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).  Translation: dont do that for the very reason you are asking: you want to do *different* things in each event.  The fact that they are related to the same control is irrelevant.

Comment: Usually we try to customize/specialize events, not turn them generic. For example, using both MouseMove and MouseDown, we can create a `MouseHoldDown(From [Point], To [Point])` or fire up a `TextBox.InvalidInput(OffendingText [String])` event..

Comment: If you want to combine events, just for the ease of reading the code, you _should_ create several specialized Method/Function or one specialized Class to monitor all those events, to fire one specific event that describes the nature of the encapsulated fired event (by passing a new e parameter that derives from EventArgs for example) _"complicate first and then simplify syndrome..."_

Comment: @Plutonix I'm greatly confused as to where to draw the line on consolidating repetitious code (i.e. code for Enter is the exact same as TextChanged.). Pushing as much repetitious code to a universal sub, I'm calling the said universal sub from within the Enter, TextChanged and Leave subs. Here's my [actual code](http://pastebin.com/b5UQQmRt). Disregarding my intent to consolidate events (I'll follow your advice), at a glance, does the linked code excerpt go too far in consolidation (and therefore against the principle you linked to)? You'll see how I'm passing the event as a parameter.

Comment: @fsintegral See my reply comment to Plutonix. I've linked to an excerpt of actual code. I'm using a universal to manage the Enter, TextChanged and Leave subs. Does this suffice as the "monitoring" you've referred to?

Comment: you can **call** other subs from events.  For example, if there is some great commonality for the _Enter and _Leave, call `CheckTBForFoo(thisTB)` from the _enter and _leave events.  When you have code that CASES out the control and the event, you have gone too far.  You want to write "specialists" to handle this or that for perhaps several controls, not jack of all trades procedures that ramble on and on trying to do everything for everyone.

Comment: that refers to using `Select Case` to work out which control or event is being processed.  Your pastebin code uses a big `IF` block to do the same.  But look at it...`ElseIf txtEvent = "Leave" Then...` you break out the Leave event to do something different than Enter, so that means the ought not be together.  There is nothing gained from consolidating if you just break it out elsewhere.  The same would go for a `Case/If` to split what to do for this control or that - if they have different rules, leave them seperate.  Consolidate to perform the same action.

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks for breaking that down. The misperceived gain was less (read "more efficient") code. Since `.Enter` and `.TextChanged` require the same action, I'll call the one sub for both events. However, for `.Leave`, I'll forgo calling a sub and will instead specify the action within the event. Regarding my use of `txtactive = CType(sender, TextBox) If (txtactive Is TextBox1) Then`, is this another example of the **control casing** you described and should my control events therefore be separate? e.g. `handles TextBox1.Enter, TextBox2.Enter`