# Is it bad practice to handle multiple event types of the same action?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, events, event-handling

## My problem:

I have `.Enter` and `.TextChanged` events that both fire the exact same code. I've combined these events under the one handler. Is this considered bad practice for any reason or in this particular instance, is it considered wise to streamline my code?

## Sample Code:

**Combined under one handler:**

```
Private Sub TextBox_EnterChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Enter, TextBox2.Enter, TextBox1.TextChanged, TextBox2.TextChanged
    'Some action.
End Sub
```

**Default separate handlers:**

```
Private Sub TextBox_Enter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Enter, TextBox2.Enter
    'Some action.
End Sub


Private Sub TextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged, TextBox2.TextChanged
    'The same action.
End Sub
```

Comment: `TextBox_EnterChanged` is not an event

Comment: @NeethuSoman I know. It's an event handler, the name of which is arbitrary. Scroll the code blocks to the right to see the events. The events are handled irrespective of how I name the event handler. Is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: @NeethuSoman, is the name of a method and is legal.

Comment: An alternative would be to keep the handlers separate, but put the code for `action` in its own method.  That way you would only need to change the action in one place.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway For context, the action of my actual code calls an external method and passes a few parameters such as the active text box and associated properties. The action is about 150 lines of code. It felt bulky to paste those lines twice when I can iterate them once by combining my events. I was [originally](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26642031/2971649) going so far as to combine all events into the single handler and passing the event type as a parameter to an external single method. I've since been educated by other members on this website that is bad practice in that it goes too far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While asking about "bad practice" can sometimes lead to overly large arguments based mostly on opinion, I would have done exactly the same. It's legal, functional, and mostly clear (unless you start handling a huge list of events). I would answer your question directly with another question:

Conversely, what would be the benefit of copy/pasting identical code into multiple methods?

So, no, I would not consider this bad practice.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I wasn't certain if it contravened the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). You may be interested in the comments of [a similar question I posted a few hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26642031/2971649). It's concerned with arguments for and against duplicitous identical code blocks.

Comment: To be a bit more clear: there is no reason to have multiple copies of the exact same code. Should you have multiple events that require similar code, try to break identical parts out to their own reusable methods, then call them from the event before/after performing the more unique code.

Comment: @ClarusDignus - The only issue I see is if you need to make changes in the future.  If the code remains this simple, then it probably won't be a big deal if you need to separate them later, but the more complex the code gets the more difficult it could be to change later.